# Finite flat pushforward of a constant sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $A$ be an abelian group and consider the associated constant sheaf $A$ on a (smooth projective) variety $Y$ (over a field).  Let $f: Y \to X$ be a surjective finite flat morphism.  Is $f_*A$ also a constant sheaf on $X$?

Comment: See @ACL's answer, and the associated comments, at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61528/is-the-direct-image-of-a-constant-sheaf-a-constant-sheaf - they seem relevant...

Comment: @peterag: Thanks, I looked at that answer.  But in this case, the morphism is finite, so the fibre is a discrete space, right?  I'm a bit confused here...

Comment: In the usual topology, or the étale topology, the map $f:\mathbb{A}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^1$ the map $z\mapsto z^2$ is a counter-example. It is finite and flat but the fiber at $0$ is a single point whereas at any other point, the fiber consists of two points. However, it is not a counter-example for the Zariski topology. Actually, I think that if $Y$ is irreducible, $A$ is the constant presheaf. Hence $f_*A$ is also a constant presheaf, and thus a constant sheaf on $X$.

Comment: @user113969. Yes, what you write is  correct: +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the image of a  constant sheaf is a constant sheaf, even  under significantly weaker  hypotheses: it suffices to require that  $Y$ be irreducible and $f$ surjective.

Actually the result is purely topological: given a surjective continuous map $f:Y\to X$ between topological maps, if  $Y$ irreducible then  the direct image of any constant sheaf $\underline A_Y$ on $Y$ is the  constant sheaf $f_*(\underline A_Y)=A_X$ on $X$.
Indeed, given an arbitrary non-empty open subset $V\subset X$ we have $$\Gamma(V,f_*(A_Y))=\Gamma (f^{-1}(V),A_Y)=A$$ the last equality resulting from $f^{-1}(V)$ being connected, like any open subset of an irreducible space . 
This proves that  $f_*(   A_Y)=A_X$.

**Warning:** Beware that the result is false for non surjective $f$.
 For example  if $Y=*$ is a point, the direct image $f_*(A_Y)$ is the sky-scraper sheaf on $X$ with stalk  $A$ at $f(*)\in X$

Comment: Thanks.  I am a bit intrigued by user113969's comment though.  What happens in etale topology?  Clearly, the map mentioned by him/her is a counterexample.  But what if the map is nicer, for example, $Y = X_E$, where $E$ is a field extension of the base and $f:Y \to X$ is the natural map?

Comment: Dear Shafi, user 113969's counterexample already works for $\mathbb C$ seen as a topological space (or analytic manifold) in its classical topology. The stalk of $f_*A$ is $A$ at $0$ and $A\oplus A$ elsewhere in the target . Does this contradict my answer? No, because $\mathbb C$ is not irreducible in the classical topology. (Actually,  the only irreducible Hausdorff spaces are one-point sets !)