# Why is this etale cohomology computation going wrong?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, etale-cohomology

Suppose $f: X \to Y$ is a finite, galois map (with galois group $\Gamma$) of curves over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$. If I pick a constant sheaf $\Lambda (\cong \mathbb Z/\ell^n$, say), then $f_*(\Lambda) \cong \Lambda^\Gamma$ (by which I simply mean $\deg(f) = |\Gamma|$ many copies of $\Lambda$) since $X\times_Y X \cong \bigsqcup_{\Gamma}X$. Moreover, the Leray spectral sequence converges immediately since all the higher pushforwards are zero (since $f$ is finite) and so
$$H^p(X,\Lambda) \cong H^p(Y,f_*\Lambda) \cong H^p(Y,\Lambda)^\Gamma.$$

However, I don't think this will be true. I don't think this is true even for $p=0$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why don't you think this is true? (I don't know whether it's true or not. I'd guess it has a chance to be true if $\ell$ doesn't divide the order of $\Gamma$.)

Comment: Are you aware of the Hochschild--Serre spectral sequence? Theorem 14.9 in this: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LEC.pdf

Comment: @QiaochuYuan For instance, for $p=0$, I think $H^0(X,\Lambda) = \Lambda$ but then $H^0(Y,\Lambda)^\Gamma = \Lambda^\Gamma$ which doesn't seem to match. Also, if this were true for $p=1$, it would say that the genus of $X$ = $\deg(f)$ genus(Y) which is also not true...

Comment: @AlexYoucis Right! Which I guess makes it even more certain that my argument is wrong. I'm sure I am missing something simple...

Comment: Is it right that $H^p(Y, \Lambda^\Gamma) = H^p (Y, \Lambda)^\Gamma$?

Comment: @Asvin: (keeping in mind that I still have no idea whether this result is true or not) What do you mean by $\Lambda^{\Gamma}$ here for $\Lambda$ a constant sheaf? I don't see any action of $\Gamma$ available other than the trivial one. I also don't understand how you are concluding that genus formula for $p = 1$. Going back to the question of whether this is actually true or not, what result are you quoting to claim that the Leray spectral sequence converges?

Comment: I guess my notation is ambiguous. By $\Lambda^\Gamma$, I just mean the set maps from $\Gamma \to \Lambda$ or in other words, $\deg(f) = |\Gamma|$ many copies of $\Lambda.$ I think this also explains my genus formula since on the right hand side, we have $\deg(f)$ many copies of a 2g(Y) dimensional module and on the left hand side, a 2g(X) dimensional module. I claim the Leray spectral sequence converges since $R^qf_* = 0$ for $q \geq 1$ since finite maps are exact (for the \'etale topology).

Comment: @hunter By $M^\Gamma$, I just mean $|\Gamma|$ many copies of $M$ - sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Oooh I figured out where I went wrong! $f_*\Lambda$ is not a direct sum of so many copies of $\Lambda$ as can be checked fibrewise - there are fewer copies over a ramified point!

Comment: @Asvin: what do you mean by a "Galois map of curves" if you're allowing such a map to be ramified? Do you mean that the corresponding field extension is Galois? That is weaker than what I would mean by "Galois map of curves," which would imply unramified.

Comment: That's right, I just mean that the corresponding field extension is Galois. I am not entirely sure what the standard terminology is Galois, it might be what you suggest.

Comment: I would call such a thing a “branched Galois” or “ramified Galois” cover, I think. For me a “Galois cover with Galois group $G$” should be a $G$-torsor and in particular etale and in particular unramified.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the statement that $f_*(\Lambda) = \Lambda^\Gamma$. While $f_*(\Lambda)(Y) = \Lambda^\Gamma$ as claimed, it is not true that the pushforward of a constant sheaf under a finite map has to be constant.

It is easy to compute the stalks of the pushforward of a finite map and we have:
$$(f_*\Lambda)_y = \bigoplus_{x \to y}\Lambda_x$$
for $x,y$ geometric points on $X,Y$ and we see that over a ramified point, we have fewer points.

Comment: Aren't Galois covers unramified?

Comment: If $X$ is connected, then shouldn't $f_{\ast}(\underline{\Lambda}_{X})(Y) = \Gamma(X,\underline{\Lambda}_{X}) = \Lambda$?

Comment: The problem is not ramified points, in fact there are unramified Galois cover and the computation is still wrong. The problem is that $f_*\Lambda$ is a locally constant sheaf, but not necessarily constant. In fact, it correspond to a representation of $\Gamma$ and has a constant subsheaf of rank 1 (or more generally of rank the number of connected component of $X$). Take for example, $X=Y=\mathbb{G}_m$ and $f:X\to Y, x\mapsto x^2$. Then; if $2$ is invertible in $\Lambda$ and $Y$, $f_*\Lambda$ splits as $\Lambda\oplus \Lambda'$ for a non trivial locally constant sheaf $\Lambda'$.

Comment: Also you said you are not working over an algebraically closed field, by $H(X,\Lambda)$, do you mean $H(X_{\overline{k}},\Lambda)$ ? If you don't, beware that $H(\operatorname{Spec} k,\Lambda)$ is the whole Galois cohomology of $k$.

Comment: @Roland, thank you for both the comments! Is the pushforward locallly constant even near a ramified point? I agree that there are problems even for a Galois cover.

Comment: No, at a ramified point, the situation is indeed even worse : the pushforward is not locally constant anymore, in fact the rank at the singular value is less than the generic rank as you said in this answer. As an example $\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{A}^1, x\mapsto x^2$, then since $\{0\}$ has a single preimage, then $(f_*\Lambda)_0=\Lambda$ is of rank 1 whereas $f_*\Lambda|_{\mathbb{A}^1\setminus\{0\}}$ is locally constant of rank 2.

Comment: See also this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352495/finite-flat-pushforward-of-a-constant-sheaf

Comment: @MinseonShin Ok, for the link, but the answer used Zariski topology and not the étale one where the situation is very different.

Comment: @Roland Thanks, I think I have resolved my confusion. Is it true that the locally constant etale sheaf $\Lambda'$ in your answer has the property that $\Gamma(Y',\Lambda') = 0$ for any etale morphism $Y' \to Y$ for which $Y' \times_{Y} X$ is connected?

Comment: @MinseonShin I have never seen it written that way, but I do believe that this is true.